# Problema ao gerar layout de janela modal com formulário usando thymeleaf

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, front-end, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Boa tarde. Estou conseguindo gerar as janelas modais do bootstrap e carregando os dados no formulário, mas o layout do formulário está ficando todo bagunçado. Vou deixar duas fotos para mostrar o que está acontecendo.

1. Como deveria ficar
   [image: Imagem mostrando como o layout da janela modal deve ser]
2. Como fica quando o Thymeleaf gera o Layout

[image: Imagem mostrando como o layout está sendo gerado pelo Thymeleaf]

Código da Modal:

```html
<!-- Modal Visualizar -->
<div class="modal fade" id="view-modal" th:id="${atendimento.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" tabindex="50" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Detalhes do Atendimento</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" th:object="${atendimento}" th:id="${atendimento.id}"  method="POST">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">Atendimento</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-11 control-label">
                  <p class="help-block">* Campo Obrigatório </p>
                </div>
                
                <!-- ==== CLIENTE ==== -->                                              
                <!-- Razão Social --> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="razaoSocial">Razão Social</label>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input id="razaoSocial" name="razaoSocial" type="text" placeholder="Razão Social" th:value="${atendimento.cliente.razaoSocial}" readonly="readonly" class="form-control input-md">
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Codigo" class="col-md-2 control-label">Código *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input id="cliente" name="cliente" th:value="${atendimento.cliente.id}" class="form-control input-md" type="text" readonly="readonly">
                  </div>
                  <label for="status" class="col-md-5 control-label">Status</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input class="form-control input-md" th:value="${atendimento.cliente.status}" readonly="readonly" type="text">                                     
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Telefone">Telefone *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                      <input id="telefone" name="telefone" class="form-control input-md" readonly="readonly" th:value="${atendimento.cliente.telefone}" placeholder="XX XXXX-XXXX" type="text" maxlength="12" OnKeyPress="formatar('## ####-####', this)">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="Celular">Celular</label>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                      <input id="celular" name="celular" class="form-control input-md" readonly="readonly" th:value="${atendimento.cliente.celular}" placeholder="XX XXXXX-XXXX" type="text" maxlength="13" OnKeyPress="formatar('## #####-####', this)">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="email">Email *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                      <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" th:value="${atendimento.cliente.email}" placeholder="email@email.com" required type="text" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ==== /. CLIENTE ====-->
                
                <hr size="30">
                
                <div class="form-group" >
                  <label for="codigoAtendimento" class="col-md-2 control-label">Código de Atendimento*</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input id="id" name="id" th:value="${atendimento.id}" class="form-control" placeholder="Exemplo: 0000252017" readonly="readonly" type="text">                               
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="col-md-3 selectContainer" >
                    <select class="form-control" name="tipoAtendimento" readonly="readonly">
                      <option value="Performance">Performance</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="col-md-3 selectContainer">
                    <select class="form-control" name="modulo" readonly="readonly">
                      <option selected th:value="${atendimento.modulo}" th:text="${atendimento.modulo}"></option>                            
                    </select>
                  </div>                                             
                  
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group" >
                  <label for="Descricao" class="col-md-2 control-label">Descrição *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input id="descricao" name="descricao" th:value="${atendimento.descricao}" class="form-control" placeholder="Descrição do Atendimento" type="text" readonly="readonly">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group date" id='datetimepicker'>
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
                      <input type="text" id="dataAtendimento" name="dataAtendimento" class="form-control" th:value="${#dates.format(atendimento.dataAtendimento, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}" readonly="readonly">
                    </div>                               
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="admUser" class="col-md-3 control-label">Nome do usuário que solicitou suporte *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input id="admUser" name="admUser" th:value="${atendimento.admUser}" class="form-control input-md" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                  </div>                                        
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="operador" class="col-md-2 control-label">Operador*</label>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input id="operador" name="operador" readonly th:value="${userName}" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" required type="text">
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group" >
                  <label for="solucao" class="col-md-2 control-label">Solução *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <textarea id="solucao" name="solucao" th:text="${atendimento.solucao}" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" cols="70" rows="10" placeholder="Descrição detalhada da solução referente ao problema apresentado pelo usuário."></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="observacao" class="col-md-2 control-label">Observação *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <textarea id="observacao" name="observacao" th:text="${atendimento.observacao}" readonly="readonly" required class="form-control" cols="70" rows="10" placeholder="Observações sobre o atendimento."></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Status" class="col-md-2 control-label">Status *</label>
                  <div class="selectContainer" name="Status">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <select class="form-control" name="statusAtendimento" >
                        <option th:value="${atendimento.statusAtendimento}" th:text="${atendimento.statusAtendimento}"></option>                           
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>          
                </div>                                
              </div>
            </div>                    
          </fieldset>
        </form> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
      </div>                                      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.Modal Visualizar -->
```

Comment: java ou javascript?

Comment: @diegofm Esse projeto é em Java.

Comment: vc esta separando por div cada bloco de label e input? poe o html pra darmos uma olhada.

Comment: @CleristonLincoln segue o link do código no pastebin, vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código lá também https://pastebin.com/H56ejXJ5